# How to make more accurate route from long lat coordinates in Postgis?

Tags: postgis

I'm new in PostGis, I'm wondering how to draw route if there are less coordinates from GPS. 
[image]

please give some useful advice in this situation

Comment: Do you want to snap the points to the line? (and eventually add missing points). Or you don't have at all the geometries of the lines?

Comment: Do you have the lines as vector/geometry in the DB? Then you should have a look at `ST_ClosesPoint(line.geom, point.geom)`. If it is just a raster image try to get the geometries ;-) Since it looks like you are using OSM it should be possible.